# taking output on console when running junit through ant script

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am using ant script and running a junit, the problem I am facing is that I am unable to get the output on console, rather I get the output in a log file.

how can I achieve that.. 
I am using the following script.

```
<target name="validate_mapping" description="Testing the Hibernate ">

    <path id="validator.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}\lib">
            <include name="Junit-Temp-Test.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <junit printsummary="yes">
        <formatter type="plain"/>
        <test name="com.ofss.fc.junit.test.SampleTest" />
        <classpath>
            <path refid="validator.classpath" />
            <path refid="lib.ext.classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </junit>    
</target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify "usefile" attribute `<formatter usefile="false" type="plain"/>`